# How to create solana new account using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, solana

I want to create Solana new account using reactjs,
I wrote this code:
[image]

And this is the error

[image: > [enter image description here][2]]

Is there any help, please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Instead, embed code and errors into your question using code formatting. Also, it seems like you accidentally formatted your whole post as quotes by starting your lines with a ">" character. You can edit your post to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You can see how this this is done in javascript in the Solana Hello World application.

https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld/blob/a41a4a0c6ec2911c8587a68e4c9e60e41d7ff4e8/src/client/utils.ts#L16

Comment: The account is created properly but @gahlouzi-ameni is trying to create a token account.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create TokenAccount, main issue that I see is that `this.payer` is not signing transaction.